# `insert-file-contents` without the comments

Tags: comment, insert

The below command insert the contents of the file `myfile.txt`.

`(insert-file-contents "~/myfile.txt")`

Is there a way to tell emacs to not insert the comments (assuming the comment syntax is known to the user and is for example`%`).

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I think the general method of handling this would be to create a temporary buffer of the file to be inserted, strip the comments and insert the remainder into the target buffer.

Comment: To add to what lawlist said, in the temporary buffer, in the first pass, delete all lines staring with `"^%"`using using `delete-matching-lines`. In the second pass, use `re-search-forward` to replace all `"%·*$"` with `""`.